# How to get rid of the Isolation Mode Layers without losing any Layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How to get rid of the Isolation Mode Layers without losing any Layers. See the image, for example, attached.

Another way to state the question would be how to convert isolated layers into normal layers.

**Issue**: when we save the isolated layers disappear. I have to get rid of this.

[image]

Important Update: while saving all the Isolation layers disappears.
[Please check here.](https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazonmyaccount/Illustrator_Issue.gif)

I hope that there must be some remedy.

Comment: To be better understand, do layers that exist when in isolation mode suddenly disappear when in normal mode? Because that doesn't sound like the way Illustrator works.

Comment: Every time you save the file in Isolation mode, pattern editing or Symbol editing, the Illustrator exit that modes before saving the file.